# Using a XAML image as a button content

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I am a beginner with Visual Studio.

I want to have separately defineable icons in my buttons. I want to achieve this using only XAML in order to keep my GUI stuff as separate as possible.

I'd like to be able to use it like this:

```
<Button x:Name="CallButton" Height="128px" Width="128px" 
        Style="{DynamicResource RoundButton}" Content="{StaticResource PhoneIcon}">
```

I have defined RoundButton and PhoneIcon in their respective Resource Dictionaries.

RoundButton:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="RoundButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Grid}"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">

            <Setter.Value>

                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

                    <Border CornerRadius="100" BorderThickness="2" x:Name="border" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">

                        <Grid>

                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                              x:Name="contentPresenter" Opacity="1" />

                        </Grid>

                    </Border>

                </ControlTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>

        </Setter>

    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

PhoneIcon:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Canvas x:Key="PhoneIcon">

        <Path Stroke="Gray" Data="m 492.438 397.75 -2.375 -7.156 c -5.625 -16.719 -24.063 -34.156 -41 -38.75 l -62.688 -17.125 c -17 -4.625 -41.25 1.594 -53.688 14.031 L 310 371.438 C 227.547 349.157 162.891 284.5 140.641 202.063 l 22.688 -22.688 c 12.438 -12.438 18.656 -36.656 14.031 -53.656 L 160.266 63 C 155.641 46.031 138.172 27.594 121.485 22.031 l -7.156 -2.406 c -16.719 -5.563 -40.563 0.063 -53 12.5 L 27.391 66.094 c -6.063 6.031 -9.938 23.281 -9.938 23.344 -1.187 107.75 41.063 211.562 117.281 287.781 76.031 76.031 179.453 118.219 286.891 117.313 0.563 0 18.313 -3.813 24.375 -9.844 l 33.938 -33.938 c 12.437 -12.437 18.062 -36.281 12.5 -53 z" />

    </Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I have merged my Resource Dictionaries in the App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <ResourceDictionary Source="RoundButton.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Icons.xaml" />

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>

</Application.Resources>
```

My problem is that while I get the image displayed, it's disproportionately big. I have tried pretty many solutions so I'm starting to lose track of the tried with my trial-and-error approach.

How to get the image show right in the center of the button with correct size?

**NB** I have trimmed some of the code I'm posting here - but I have also tested the code I'm posting here and the problem persists.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `Grid` instead of a Canvas in your `PhoneIcon` resource, and set the Path's `Stretch` property. This would scale the Path to a Size that fits the Button's bounds:

```
<Grid x:Key="PhoneIcon">
    <Path Stretch="Uniform" ... />
</Grid>
```

You may even set the Grid size explicitly:

```
<Grid x:Key="PhoneIcon" Width="80">
    <Path Stretch="Uniform" ... />
</Grid>
```

An even simpler solution would be to use the Path without any container:

```
<Path x:Key="PhoneIcon" Width="80" Stretch="Uniform" ... />
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thank you! But why didn't grid work and why did viewbox work there? I tried viewbox earlier but in a different place -- obviously it didn't work then. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I forgot to mention the simpler solution, which would be to set the Stretch property on the Path. I've edited the answer.